# How to make li class active dynamically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My HTML code is

```
   <div id="sidebar"><a href="#" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>Dashboard</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="{{route('ScamType.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Scam Type</span></a> </li>
          <li> <a href="{{route('ScamDatabase.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-signal"></i> <span>Scam Database</span></a> </li>
          <li> <a href="{{route('ScamStory.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-inbox"></i> <span>Scam Story</span></a> </li>
          <li><a href="{{route('KeyWord.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> <span>Keyword</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="{{route('Category.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> <span>Category</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="{{route('SubCategory.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> <span>Sub Category</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here i gave li class active as like in bootstrap and its not working, but i don't know how to give in laravel and i am very beginner of laravel, so please avoid minus votes and give me the right solution for it.. How Should i change my code to get li class active dynamically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ternary operator. For example, you can check URI for the current route:

```
<li{{ request()->is('scam-types') ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
```

You can also use `*` as wildcard:

```
<li{{ request()->is('scam-type-number-*') ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
```

Or you can check route name:

```
<li{{ request()->route()->getName() === 'ScamType.index' ? ' class="active"' : '' }}>
```

Comment: Thank You @Alexey , It doesn't work.. What else can i do??

Comment: @ManiRaj both ways are definitely work, I'm using these in my projects. Please explain what exactly you're doing, what error do you get etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code to write each li tag for check some text in URL

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ScamType") !== false){
   echo "active";
}
```

Write above code in class.

Ex.

```
<li class="{{ if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "ScamType") !== false){  echo "active"; } }}"><a href="{{route('ScamType.index')}}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Scam Type</span></a> </li>
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply but it still not working, What's wrong in my code i don't know..

Answer (score 2):

From above answer I have try and doesnt work because `class="active"` must be `class=active`

```
<li><a class="{{ request()->routeIs('about.index*') ? 'active-menu' : '' }}" href="{{route('about.index')}}"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

routeIs('Route_Name*') ? 'active-menu' : '' }}">

In Route Name just write Route name defined in Routes